# Tomcat application can't connect to Active Directory when running as a Windows service

Tags: active-directory, windows-service

I have a strange scenario that I haven't been able to find any details on anywhere. I have an application running in tomcat that connects to an Active Directory server that works perfectly when I start the application up from a command prompt as an Administrator (via startup.bat file) it connects to Active Directory fine.

However, when installed as a service, the application does not connect to Active Directory. I believe that the startup options are all the same, and am thinking I am missing something around how the service is run, or when a service is run, that it 'looks different' from the perspective of the Active Directory server. Has anyone run into this scenario before?

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: What account does the service run as?

Comment: What do you mean by "access active directory" (sic)? Are you doing some kind of LDAP-based operations in your service? If so, how are you storing the credentials used to bind to the LDAP server?